search bar not appearing correctly in flutter app
im not sure why the search bar is displaying incorrectly when its segregated to being its own component.
issue::
when the code below is displayed inside of SearchBar incorrectly:
TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Search',
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
      ),
      onChanged: onChanged,
    );

when the code is outside of SearchBar it is displayed correctly
code1:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:worknow_front_end/ui/components/navigators/comp/category_module_list.dart';
import 'package:worknow_front_end/ui/components/navigators/home_side_navigator.dart';

class HomeSideNavigator extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> menu_categories;
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> menu_modules;

  const HomeSideNavigator({
    Key? key,
    required this.menu_categories,
    required this.menu_modules,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeSideNavigatorState createState() => _HomeSideNavigatorState();
}

class _HomeSideNavigatorState extends State<HomeSideNavigator> {
  String _searchQuery = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 200,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SearchBar(onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              _searchQuery = value.toLowerCase();
            });
          }),

          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Search',
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
            ),
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _searchQuery = value.toLowerCase();
              });
            },
          ),
          CategoryModuleList(
            categories: widget.menu_categories,
            modules: widget.menu_modules,
            searchQuery: _searchQuery,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

code2:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SearchBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final ValueChanged<String> onChanged;

  const SearchBar({
    Key? key,
    required this.onChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Search',
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
      ),
      onChanged: onChanged,
    );
  }
}

the screen shot below shows that SearchBar is not displaying correctly


i was importing the wrong search bar!
